# Facebook Share text alone?

Tags: facebook, social-networking, share

is possible to write code(like any links or buttons) only for share text alone without any images & url's in [facebook](http://facebook.com).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be yes, did you have a look at the facebook documentation?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share

Answer (score 1):

You have to use streamPublish, you can't use Facebook's automated links. You can include or leave out anything you want.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments